# How to set url parameter in header

Tags: apache, header

I have a client request that cannot contains custom headers, but server-side I need a hearder (let's call him foo).

So I have this url path/to/bar?foo=value

I want that my apache conf that the foo value and put it in a header.
I haven't so far find a solution :(.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I find a solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:.*&)?foo=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ - [env=foo:%1]
<IfDefine !foo>
    RequestHeader set Foo %{foo}e env=foo
</IfDefine>
```